# Javascript and PHP code doesn't function anymore after adding bind_parameter to prevent SQL-injection

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I created a code that retrieves data from a DB using ajax and Json in Javascript and PHP. In the end, a dropdown list is populated with the data from the query. It worked fine until I added the bind_parameter functions to prevent SQL-injection. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

JavaScript:

```
function getCompetitie()
{
   seizoen = $("#Seizoen-text").val();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'get_competitie.inc.php',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: {seizoen: seizoen},
    success: function(response){
        $("#Competitie-list").empty();
        $("#Competitie-list").append("<option>Competitie</option>");
        var len = response.length;
        alert(len);
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var comp = response[i]['Competitie'];
            $("#Competitie-list").append("<option value='"+comp+"'>"+comp+"</option>");
        }
    }
});
}
```

PHP code WITHOUT binding parameters (works fine):

```
<?php
include "includes/dbh.inc.php";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Competitie FROM kalender WHERE Seizoen='".$_POST['seizoen']."' ORDER BY Seizoen DESC;";    

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $competitie = $row['Competitie'];
    $result_array[] = array("Competitie"=>$competitie);
}
echo json_encode($result_array);

?>
```

PHP code WITH binding parameters (does not work) :

```
<?php

include "includes/dbh.inc.php";
$seiz= $_POST['seizoen'];
if (empty($seiz)) {
    exit ();
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Competitie FROM kalender WHERE Seizoen=? ORDER BY Seizoen DESC;";    
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
        exit ();
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $seiz);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $result_array = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $result_array = array();
                $seizoen = $row['Seizoen'];
                $result_array[] = array("Seizoen"=>$seizoen);
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            echo json_encode($result_array);
        }
        else {
            exit ();                    
        }
    }
}

?>
```

All I seem to be getting is "undefined" in the dropdown box. Anybody a suggestion where I went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're also not pushing the first row that you fetch onto `$result_array`

Comment: Or perhaps due to the new `array("Seizoen"=>` instead of `array("Competitie"=>`. "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. At least look at the generated output, or add `var_dump` calls to narrow the mishap down.

Comment: I think `$row['Seizoen'];` would be more of a problem, since that isn't being pulled from the database.

Comment: It's worth mentioning also that your code could be reduced to about 5 lines if you were using PDO. It's much less verbose, especially when dealing with prepared statements.

Comment: Miken32, I am not at all familiar with PDO. Any suggestions how the code would look like then? Or where I could find some sort of manual? Thanks !

Comment: The same place you (hopefully) found a manual for mysqli. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Miken32 Thx ! That is crystal clear now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the column `Competitie` in `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Competitie..`

So, fix this:

```
//if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //remove this line
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $competitie = $row['Competitie'];
    $result_array[] = array("Competitie"=>$competitie);
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Or select the Seizoen column also.

Comment: And a fix to remove the line that is resetting the array every loop.

Comment: @miken32 it's not a typo, it's [Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_language) :-D

Comment: Thanks, Felippe. That works like a charm! Strange though that it did work without the parameter bindings. Anyway, thanks a million!